# Reload Jquery DataGrid Table - not working

Tags: c#, jquery, json, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

I have little to no experience working with jQuery or JSON.  However, I found a great little tutorial online that walked me through the steps of creating a jQuery DataGrid Table - which was exactly what I needed.  And it works great.

Problem is, I need to reload the table at times.  And that, I cannot get working.

Here is my Controller

```
public ActionResult AddSupplies()
{
    var q = db.ICS_Orders;           
    return View(q);           
}
```

Here is my Partial View with DataGrid

```
l IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Orders>
@{
Layout = null;
}

<div id="divSupplies">
<h3>Monthly Requisition: Supplies and Forms</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Requested Supplies</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="supplies-data-table"
                       class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                       style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                               
                            <th>Requisition Number</th>
                            <th>Supplies</th>
                            <th>Amount Ordered</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @*@foreach (var asset in Model)*@
                            @foreach (var asset in Model.Where(w => w.RequisitionNumber == ViewBag.TransNum))
                            {
                            <tr>

                                <td>@asset.RequisitionNumber</td>
                                <td>@asset.Supply</td>
                                <td>@asset.UnitsOrdered</td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr />
<!-- Add Java Script-->

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/CheckContacts.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Supplies.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#supplies-data-table').DataTable();


 });
```

All of my research shows that the proper way to reload the table is with:

```
  $('#supplies-data-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

But this does not work. I get the following JSON error

"DataTables warning:  table id=supplies-data-table - invalid JSON response.

I can't seem to find anything that helps me understand why, or how to resolve it.  I am puzzled that the table will load the first time, and load on post back properly.  But when forcing to reload - I get this error and it fails.

Comment: `ajax.reload()` reloads the table from the ajax source. Your code doesn't show any sign of an ajax source. You're also initialising `DataTable` on an already populated table, so how exactly does the reload aid you?

Comment: You need to load your table empty (HTML); set `ajax` option to request the data from the backed; make your backed script respond with table source data in valid format; use `ajax.reload()` whenever you need to refresh your table. Refer to datatables.net for detailed description of mentioned options, API methods and relevant code samples.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended, I reconfigured the code to load the table from ajax source.  I guess, I didn't fully understand how jQuery DataTables work. After reading the comments, I did some further research online and figured things out.  Here is what I did

View where Table is located

```
<!-- Begin Jquery DataTable-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
<div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
<h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Requested Supplies</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Requisition Number</th>
<th>Supply Name</th>
<th>Amount Requested</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- End Jquery DataTable-->
```

My Jquery to Load The Table (on document.ready)

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
"ajax": {
"url": "/ICSNewOrders/loaddata",
"type": "GET",
 "datatype": "json"
 },
 "columns": [
 { "data": "RequisitionNumber", "autoWidth": true },
 { "data": "Supply", "autoWidth": true },
 { "data": "UnitsOrdered", "autoWidth": true }
 ]
 });
 });
```

My loaddata from my controller

```
public ActionResult loaddata()
{

ViewBag.TransNum = TempData["ReqNo"];
TempData.Keep();

String ReqID = Convert.ToString(TempData["ReqNo"].ToString());

using (ICSContext dc = new ICSContext())
{
dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
var data = dc.ICS_Orders.Where(s => s.RequisitionNumber == ReqID).OrderBy(a => a.RequisitionNumber).ToList();

return Json(new
{
data = data
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

And finally, to refresh the Jquery DataTable . . .

```
$('#myTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

All works now.